# Get text of an element of a dropdown disabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to get the text of the element.

This is the dropdown box in disable mode:

```
<select disabled="" readonly="readonly" onchange="onChange('incident.priority');" style="; " id="incident.priority" class="form-control readonly disabled" ng-non-bindable="true" name="incident.priority">
    <option value="">-- None --</option>
    <option value="1">1 - Critical</option>
    <option value="2">2 - High</option>
    <option value="3">3 - Moderate</option>
    <option value="4">4 - Low</option>
    <option value="5">5 - Planning</option>
</select>
```

I am using:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='incident.priority']"));
String s = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].text" + "", element);
System.out.println("Priorityvalue= " + s);
```

The output is null. I want to get that disable element text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm well I am not sure how the disabled attribute will affect this but when working with dropdown boxes user the `SelectElement` class.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[id='incident.priority']"));
SelectElement elementDdl = new SelectElement(element);
var text = elementDdl.SelectedOpiton.Text;
```

Now this is C# code but the methods and classes should all be named similarly.

Comment: Glad its working, if this solved your issue could you please accept the answer so others will know it worked.